# Gateway NV52 won't hibernate when pressing power button or closing lid

Tags: hibernate

I was having a problem with my Gateway laptop not resuming from hibernate. I researched the problem and tried resetting the hibernate file size with powercfg which seems to have solved that problem but created a new one. Now, even though I have power options set to hibernate when power button is pressed or lid is closed, instead it sleeps. I've tried several different fixes including resetting all the power options but nothing has worked. It will hibernate when I use the shut down option but ignores my power button and lid closing settings.